# Predecessor probabilities regarding Uniform Attachment Tree

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, random-graphs

**Summary:**

My question is: What is a formal argument for the fact that for a given uniform attachment tree $G$ with arbitrary vertex labels, each possible predecessor (i.e., the tree before its last step of construction) is equally likely?

---

**More details:**

A uniform attachment tree is a tree which grows according to the following procedure:

1. Start with an initial vertex, say $V \gets \{ v_1 \}$.
2. For $k = 2, \dots, n$, attach vertex $v_k$ to an existing vertex $w \in V$. $w$ is chosen uniformly at random.

Therefore you end up with a random tree of size $n$ with $n-1$ edges.

Now, **when given a tree $G$ with arbitrary vertex labels** (i.e., we do not know which vertex was added at which step), **we would like to know what the probabilities are for the previous step.** **My intuition says that each possible predecessor is equally likely,** or in other words
$$
\mathbb P (G_{n-1} = H ~|~ G) = \frac 1 l
$$
where $l \in \mathbb N$ is the number of leaves and $H$ a possible predecessor.

A possible predecessor of $G$ is a graph which is similar to $G$ except that a leaf vertex $v$ has been removed from the vertex set( and consequently all edges which contain $v$).

**Despite having an inituition for the problem, I'd like to have some formal proof of this.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The predecessor probabilities are not all equal.

Consider the following tree:

```
a -- b -- c -- d
          |
          e
```

There are $28$ possible orders in which this tree could have been built. Of them, $8$ end with `e` (`abcde`, `bacde`, `bcade`, `bcdae`, `cbade`, `cbdae`, `cdbae`, `dcbae`), and $8$ end with `d` (`abced`, `baced`, `bcaed`, `bcead`, `cbaed`, `cbead`, `cebad`, `ecbad`), but $12$ end in `a` (`bcdea`, `bceda`, `cbdea`, `cdbea`, `cdeba`, `cbeda`, `cebda`, `cedba`, `dcbea`, `dceba`, `ecbda`, `ecdba`), so the three possible predecessors have probabilities of $\frac27$, $\frac27$, and $\frac37$.

Some intuition for this calculation: we can think of a uniform attachment tree as a "uniform detachment" tree in which we start with the tree above and detach leaves one at a time until we're left with a single vertex. All possible detachment orders are equally likely, because they are all reverse orders of how a uniform attachment tree could have been built. In the tree above:

- If `d` or `e` is detached first, then we are left with $P_4$, which has $8$ detachment orders: for each step, we decide whether to detach the left leaf or the right leaf.
- If `a` is detached first, then we are left with $K_{1,3}$, which has $12$ detachment orders: there's $3 \cdot 2$ ways to detach two leaves of $K_{1,3}$, which leaves us with a $P_2$ that we can turn into a vertex in $2$ ways.

In general, the probabilities of the predecessors are proportional to the number of detachment orders they have. This has a recursive definition: if $d(T)$ is the number of detachment orders of a tree $T$, then $$d(T) = \sum_{v \in L(T)} d(T-v)$$ where $L(T)$ is the set of leaves of $T$. If $G_1, \dots, G_n$ is the sequence of trees built by uniform attachment, then $$\Pr[G_{n-1} = T-v \mid G_n = T] = \frac{d(T-v)}{d(T)}$$ for all $v \in L(T)$.

Comment: Thank you so much for your work! This really helped a lot. There's one further thing I'd like to ask though. 

You say that '... so the three possible predecessors have probabilities of 2/7, 2/7, and 3/7.'

With this you automatically assume that each build order is equally likely. Is this always true and what would be a formal argument for this?

Comment: Each build order is equally likely, because each build order has probability $\frac12 \cdot \frac13 \cdots \frac1{n-1} = \frac1{(n-1)!}$: when we add a vertex to $G_{k-1}$ to get $G_k$, we have $k-1$ places to put it, which are equally likely, and only one choice corresponds to the build order we want.